# pom.xml giving same error everytimr i create new spring project?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have used https://start.spring.io/ to create a new spring-boot project, choosing maven and spring-web as my dependency.

But as soon as I import this to my Eclipse as Existing maven project, I am getting some error in my pom.xml file, and I am getting it every time I make new spring-boot project.

**Error Message:**

```
Failure to transfer net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:629)
```

**Below is the code of my pom.xml file: The error is coming at the 3rd line below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.serviceonepavilion.customerapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootH2IntegrationNew</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run maven project update with

> force update snapshots

option selected.

A specific jar was not downloaded properly. Retrying would solve in most cases.